# How to explode array of map in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

Consider a table `my_table` with the following structure:

```
>> describe my_table

id               bigint
info_detail      map<bigint,array<string>>
```

If I explode `info_detail`, I end up with arrays:

```
>> select explode(info_detail) as (info_id, detail) 
   from my_table

   info_id  detail
   112344   ["something about 112344", "other things"]
   342302   ["something about 342302"]
```

How to explode `detail` as well, so result looks something like this:

```
   info_id  detail
   112344   "something about 112344"
   112344   "other things"
   342302   "something about 342302"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to explode the array after explode the map as follow

```
select info_id, d from (
select explode(info_detail) as (info_id, detail) 
from my_table
) t lateral view explode(detail) detailexploded as d;
```

Comment: this is a clean solution

Answer (score -1):

You have to `explode` twice, once on the `map` column and then on the resulting `array` in it.

```
select tbl.info_id,tbl1.details
from my_table m
lateral view explode(info_detail) tbl as info_id,detail 
lateral view explode(detail) tbl1 as details
```

Comment: Its failing the `explode` on the the resulting array: `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10081]: UDTF's are not supported outside the SELECT clause, nor nested in expressions`

Comment: Instead of the explode on the array, adding this after the first explode seems to work:  `LATERAL VIEW explode(detail) test_tbl as u_detail`